# Binaries in openCL (C++)

Tags: c++, c++11, opencl

Suppose I had a program in openCL:

```
...

const unsigned char* binaries;
size_t binaries_size;

assign_binaries(&binaries, &binaries_size); // my assign function, assigns bin and bin_size

std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>> Binaries;

cl::Program prog = cl::Program(context, device_list, Binaries, &binary_status, &err);

...
```

How would I go about pushing

```
binaries
```

and

```
binaries_size
```

into

```
Binaries
```

?

In the [OpenCL docs](https://github.khronos.org/OpenCL-CLHPP/classcl_1_1_program.html), it says:

```
Binaries: A vector of pairs of a pointer to a binary object and its length.
```

However, this makes no sense to me, as there is an obvious type mismatch.

Comment: This is what I found confusing (in the link provided): `typedef vector< vector< unsigned char > >  Binaries` What is `vector`? Is it `std::vector`? Is it `cl::vector`? While looking around I just found [Open C++ Bindings - Compatibility](https://github.khronos.org/OpenCL-CLHPP/index.html#compatibility): _For the 2.0 header we now assume the presence of the standard library unless requested otherwise. We use std::array, std::vector, std::shared_ptr and std::string throughout to safely manage memory and reduce the chance of a recurrance of earlier memory management bugs._

Comment: In this case, my (now deleted) answer even might have worked. You may try `cl::Program prog
  = cl::Program(context, device_list,
    { std::vector<unsigned char>(binaries, binaries + binaries_size) }, 
    &binary_status, &err);`. Btw. do you use OpenCL 1.1 or OpenCL 2.0? (Because there seem to be differences concerning `vector`)

Comment: ok, shame: I actually really liked the other answer ... thanks anyhow. Its openCL 1.2 I believe.

Comment: I still can undelete it. I was a bit worried when I realized that the `vector` in the OpenCL doc. is not necessarily the `std::vector`. (I must admit I'm a bit experienced in C++ but not at all concerning OpenCL.) After having found out what's now in my 1st comment, it might be even valuable.

Comment: Please, have a look at the [Compatibility](https://github.khronos.org/OpenCL-CLHPP/index.html#compatibility) link. They mentioned as well how to handle containers prior OpenCL 2.0...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I go about pushing
>
> ```
> binaries
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> binaries_size
> ```
>
> into
>
> ```
> Binaries
> ```
>
> ?

There are many ways to accomplish this.

**TL;DR**: The most compact code to achieve OPs intention is probably:

```
cl::Program prog
  = cl::Program(context, device_list,
    { std::vector<unsigned char>(binaries, binaries + binaries_size) }, 
    &binary_status, &err);
```

---

A longer story:

An MCVE to demonstrate two:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// the OpenCL typedef
using Binaries = std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>>;

void print(const Binaries& binaries)
{
  std::cout << "Binaries: [" << binaries.size() << "]: {\n";
  for (const std::vector<unsigned char>& binary : binaries) {
    std::cout << "  [" << binary.size() << "]: {" ;
    const char* sep = " ";
    for (const unsigned char value : binary) {
      std::cout << sep << "0x"
        << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (unsigned)value;
      sep = ", ";
    }
    std::cout << " }\n";
  }
  std::cout << "}\n";
}

int main()
{
  // sample data
  const unsigned char data[] = {
    0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08
  };
  // OPs initial exposure of data
  const unsigned char *binaries = data;
  const size_t binaries_size = std::size(data);
  // filling a Binaries var.:
  Binaries vecBinaries1;
  vecBinaries1.push_back(
    std::vector<unsigned char>(binaries, binaries + binaries_size));
  print(vecBinaries1);
  // or
  const Binaries vecBinaries2(1, std::vector<unsigned char>(binaries, binaries + binaries_size));
  print(vecBinaries2);
}
```

Output:

```
Binaries: [1]: {
  [8]: { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08 }
}
Binaries: [1]: {
  [8]: { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08 }
}
```

Please, note that data is prepared in `binaries`, and then copied into the constructor `std::vector<unsigned char>(binaries, binaries + binaries_size)` of `std::vector`.

`std::vector` provides a variety of [constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector). In this case, the constructor with `first` and `last` iterator is used:

```
template< class InputIt >
vector( InputIt first, InputIt last,
        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

(It's flavor `(5)` in the linked doc.)

However, this might be an unnecessary copy-step. Providing the data in a `std::vector<unsigned char>` from the beginning could be used to get rid of this.

The [push_back()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) can be used with move semantic (which prevents a 2<sup>nd</sup> unnecessary deep-copy). (It's flavor `(2)` in the linked doc.)
If the constructor of the inner vector is passed as argument directly, it results in an RValue which will trigger the move semantic automagically.

If there is an intermediate storage of the inner vector (e.g. in a local variable), the move semantic still can be forced with `std::move()`:

```
  std::vector<unsigned char> vecBinary3(binaries, binaries + binaries_size);
  Binaries vecBinaries3;
  vecBinaries3.push_back(std::move(vecBinary3));
  print(vecBinaries3);
```

Output:

```
Binaries: [1]: {
  [8]: { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08 }
}
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3857efee07968d0b)

---

I also added brace initialization (which in this case is [direct-list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)).

```
  const Binaries vecBinaries4 {
    std::vector<unsigned char>(binaries, binaries + binaries_size)
  };
  print(vecBinaries4);
```

Output:

```
Binaries: [1]: {
  [8]: { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08 }
}
```

(I must admit, I still consider brace init. a little bit scaring. Hence, I struggled to mention it at all but I should for completeness.)

In certain cases, e.g. if you have a vector of integrals, you have to be careful to distinguish the constructor with size `n` and an initial fill value from the constructor with an initialization list of two values.
For both, you have to provide two integral values, but the kind and number of brackets decide which constructor is used. This can result in confusion easily.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void print(const std::vector<int>& values)
{
  std::cout << '{';
  const char* sep = " ";
  for (const int value : values) {
    std::cout << sep << value;
    sep = ", ";
  }
  std::cout << " }\n";
}

int main()
{
  // sample 1:
  print({ 1, 2 });
  // sample 2:
  print(std::vector<int>(1, 2));
  // sample 3:
  print(std::vector<int>{ 1, 2 });
  // sample 4:
  print(std::vector<int>({ 1, 2 }));
}
```

Output:

```
{ 1, 2 }
{ 2 }
{ 1, 2 }
{ 1, 2 }
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b42add66db329619)